# Change default size of nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm starting to use this awesome library and I want to do a very simple thing: change the size of my nodes.

When I get the nodes from my server, they have a `size` attribute, which is an integer between 1 and 6. I would like to display the size of the node in consequence.

I've tried with the `weight` attribute:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.galaxy.nodes.length; i++) {
        cy.add({
            group: 'nodes',
            data: { id: self.galaxy.nodes[i].id.toString(), weight: self.galaxy.nodes[i].size },
            position: { x: self.galaxy.nodes[i].x , y: self.galaxy.nodes[i].y}
        });
    }
```

But unfortunately, the size remains constant, and I can't find a direction in the doc. Do you have some clue for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `width` and `height` of nodes in your [stylesheet](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style), probably [using a mapper](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/mappers) on `weight`.